# faile to resolved " /usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: 14.04, android, gcc, ubuntu-for-android, android-sdk

I tried to `make` the gcc4.6.2 for building android 2.3.7 system. 
I have installed `linux-libc-dev` with different version(`3.8.0` & `4.4.0`) and different architecture(`linux-libc-dev` & `linux-libc-dev:i386`) but still encountered the following errors:

I do not know how to fix the making of the gcc4.6.2 after viewing all kinds of discussion about this problem on web site. Can anyone give me one hand to show me how to fix that?

```
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:93,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:29:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [_muldi3.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:93,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:29:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [_negdi2.o] Error 1
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:93,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:29:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directoryIn file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:93,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:29:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [_ucmpdi2.o] Error 1

compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [_lshrdi3.o] Error 1
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:93,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:29:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directoryIn file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:93,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:29:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:93,
                 from ../../../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:29:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directorymake[3]: *** [_ashldi3.o] Error 1

compilation terminated.

make[3]: *** [_cmpdi2.o] Error 1
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [_ashrdi3.o] Error 1
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/paultsai/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/32/libgcc'
# If this is the top-level multilib, build all the other
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 14.05.5 system (YMMV), `/usr/include/asm/errno.h` is provided by the following packages:

```
linux-headers-*
linux-libc-dev:amd64
linux-libc-dev:i386
```

Comment: I am not quite sure which packages should I install for the compilation.My workstation is for Ubuntu16.04 LTS(xienal) , so should I need to install all the package above you listed above ? Does these packages relate to the Ubuntu Version while building the android 2.3.7(Gingerbread) Operation System ?

Comment: Agreed that this is broken in Ubuntu 16.04.  /usr/include/linux/errno.h contains: